# Type Set does not take parameters

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package set;

import java.util.*;

public class Set 
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String [] things = {"appple", "bob", "ham", "bob", "bacon"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(things);

    System.out.printf("%s ", list);
    System.out.println();

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
    System.out.printf("%s ", set);

  }

}
```

When I try to run this program I keep getting this error for my set declaration. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to Read naming convention first if you are new to OOPS from here  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: You're trying to have 2 different things have the same name. Name your main class something other than `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

Rename your `public class Set` class to a name that doesn't hide `java.util.Set`.

Your custom `Set` class doesn't take any type parameters. That's why `Set<String>` doesn't pass compilation.

For example:

```
package set;

import java.util.*;

public class SetTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String [] things = {"appple", "bob", "ham", "bob", "bacon"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(things);

        System.out.printf("%s ", list);
        System.out.println();

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
        System.out.printf("%s ", set);  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You named your own class `Set`, hiding the standard class `Set` in package `java.util`.

Rename your class to something else than `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

You have shadowed the `java.util.Set` import by naming your own local class `Set` (`set.Set` has a higher scope visibility and isn't generic). You could rename `set.Set`, or use the fully qualified name (and the diamond operator `<>`). Change

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

to something like

```
java.util.Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not a good idea to name the classes that are already present in Java API etc.

Adding this will be enough

```
java.util.Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

Still you make some change to the existing

```
package set;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class Set {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] things = { "appple", "bob", "ham", "bob", "bacon" };
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(things);

        System.out.printf("%s ", list);
        System.out.println();

        java.util.Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
        System.out.printf("%s ", set);

    }
}
```